# The problem with getting the page data Strapi

Tags: javascript

My problem is as follows. I have some frontend developers in my team, I built them a simple backend on Strapi and can run it on my computer. By pulling my changes from github they can't retrieve data from the backend, the problem is exactly that I don't understand where exactly I need to configure permission to read files from db =((

I've tried so many different things.

Comment: Hello, if you really expect some help I would suggest adding details on the error you are dealing with and also the "different things" you have done and tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the data itself is at `/.tmp/data.db` so if you want to share this, you either need to make sure it's tracked or manually send it to someone. (since `.tmp` should be in gitignore by default)

Realistically, I don't think this file should be tracked as that would probably result in a lot of conflicts and issues. Probably best to create a clean copy of the database with only the essential parts, save it somewhere, and share it with the rest of your team.

Comment: I'll try to figure this out. thank you 

Comment: we commented .tmp in gitignore and we managed to output the markup and tittle, but there is a problem with the photo, the developers do not see the photos, but the text comes to them

Comment: @влад The photos are in a different place as well. they should be under `public/uploads` and I'm pretty sure this is unversioned as well in git. Again, these things are unversioned for a good reason, adding them to git is probably not a great idea but you can judge your use-case for yourself

Comment: Thank you very much, my team can see the pictures. 
A virtual bouquet from me to you thank you very much 